# Fast Inverse Sqrt() [from Quake3 source code] works in Visual Studio, but not Eclipse?

Tags: c

I have the following function in a C program:

```
float invsqrt_32(float number) {
    long int i; /* expected to be 32 bits */
    float x2;
    float y;
 
    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    
    i = * ( long int * ) &number;                       
    i = 0x5f375a86 - ( i >> 1 );               
    y = * ( float * ) &i;
    
    y *= ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) );   
    y *= ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) );   
    return (y * ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) )); }
```

It is adapted from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root), with some improvements/adaptations made based on our needs and further studies.

With the input

```
number = 4.52949917e-06
```

after the magic number and bit-shif operation, on Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 (default compiler) I get

```
i = 1139498105
```

but in Eclipse 2021.09 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Linux gcc) I get

```
i = -3074621553247560583
```

I do not understand how this is happening.
What should I do to find the source of the difference?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250069/discussion-on-question-by-federico-fast-inverse-sqrt-from-quake3-source-code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by using `long int` type which is 64-bit long on 64-bit Linux while this type is 32-bit-long on 64-bit Windows. The type should be same length of IEEE 754 `float` which is 32-bit long.

The proper solution should use `int32_t` from `stdint.h` but from comment it is indicated that the platform is not properly configured and `int32_t` is actually 64-bit long.

The workaround is using `int` rather than `long int` which is 32-bit long on both Linux and Windows platforms.

```
float invsqrt_32(float number) {
    int i; /* expected to be 32 bits */
    float x2;
    float y;
 
    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    
    i = * (int * ) &number;                       
    i = 0x5f375a86 - ( i >> 1 );               
    y = * ( float * ) &i;
    
    y *= ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) );   
    y *= ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) );   
    return (y * ( 1.5F - ( x2 * y * y ) )); }
```

Note, that the solution technically violates "strict aliasing rule" which forbids accessing object of type `float` via a pointer to `int`. To be fully compliant, the reinterpretation should be done by other means like cast by union.

```
union {
  float f;
  int i;
} u = { number };
i = u.i;
```